# 20.10: Frequent crashes (browser tabs & gnome-shell), seemingly related to memory

Tags: gnome-shell, ram, crash, browser, 20.10

I'm running into fairly frequent process crashes on Ubuntu 20.10, some reproducible and some random. This has been going on for at least two months already.

The most noticable crashes are in web browsers, both Chromium and Firefox. They mostly occur on fairly heavy pages: I can reliably trigger a near-immediate crash with [this NYTimes page](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html) (it will load the page and display some page elements before crashing when starting to draw the map), but can also occur more randomly on other pages (like Jupyter Notebooks). Only the tab crashes ('Oh Snap!' on Chromium), the browser process itself is fine. Chromium usually crashes with `SIGTRAP` although I've also seen `SIGILL` and error code `64000`. Firefox segfaults.

Next to that, `gnome-shell` also crashes quite often (once every hour or so), randomly but triggered by some interaction (like opening the Application picker). My screen hangs for a few seconds, the screen goes purple and then all windows are redrawn (I'm not logged out). Crashes of `gnome-shell` don't coincide with the browser tab crashes.
I haven't noticed any other processes crashing frequently, but I don't tend to use many other applications, so the issue might not be restricted to the browsers and `gnome-shell`.

Looking at logs, the problems *seem* related to memory. The logs are inconsistent (different processes, sometimes no additional diagnostics), but these stand out to me:

```
Mar  3 07:39:29 victor kernel: [  138.399624] traps: chrome[12805] trap int3 ip:561d0936f29d sp:7ffc4861f280 error:0 in chrome[561d0917e000+754a000]
Mar  3 07:39:29 victor chromium_chromium.desktop[12805]: [12805:1:0303/073929.862778:FATAL:page_allocator_internals_posix.h(232)] Check failed: . : Cannot allocate memory (12)
```

```
Mar  2 07:33:31 victor kernel: [  228.984618] traps: chrome[3937] trap invalid opcode ip:55e3689bfb73 sp:7ffe3bd00350 error:0 in chrome[55e36626c000+7ccd000]
Mar  2 07:33:31 victor systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 4003/UID 0).
Mar  2 07:33:38 victor systemd-coredump[4004]: Process 3937 (chrome) of user 1000 dumped core.#012#012Stack trace of thread 1:#012#0  0x000055e3689bfb73 n/a (chrome + 0x4479b73)#012#1  0x000055e3689bf73f n/a (chrome + 0x447973f)#012#2  0x000055e368afe5c8 n/a (chrome + 0x45b85c8)#012#3  0x000055e36cacf9c5 n/a (chrome + 0x85899c5)#012#4  0x000055e36caba7b3 n/a (chrome + 0x85747b3)#012#5  0x000055e36be46f44 n/a (chrome + 0x7900f44)#012#6  0x000055e36c2996c1 n/a (chrome + 0x7d536c1)#012#7  0x000055e36be4803d n/a (chrome + 0x790203d)#012#8  0x000055e36c9b3444 n/a (chrome + 0x846d444)#012#9  0x000055e36c9b5804 n/a (chrome + 0x846f804)#012#10 0x000055e369b54e03 n/a (chrome + 0x560ee03)#012#11 0x000055e369b58152 n/a (chrome + 0x5612152)#012#12 0x000055e369b575ce n/a (chrome + 0x56115ce)#012#13 0x000055e36c9b0ad0 n/a (chrome + 0x846aad0)#012#14 0x000055e36c08b8ca n/a (chrome + 0x7b458ca)#012#15 0x000055e36c1d916d n/a (chrome + 0x7c9316d)#012#16 0x000055e36c8f86c6 n/a (chrome + 0x83b26c6)#012#17 0x000055e36c748a13 n/a (chrome + 0x8202a13)#012#18 0x000055e36c7456df n/a (chrome + 0x81ff6df)#012#19 0x000055e36c745eff n/a (chrome + 0x81ffeff)#012#20 0x000055e368a3553f n/a (chrome + 0x44ef53f)#012#21 0x000055e368a454a1 n/a (chrome + 0x44ff4a1)#012#22 0x000055e368a57eb9 n/a (chrome + 0x4511eb9)#012#23 0x000055e368e789e8 n/a (chrome + 0x49329e8)#012#24 0x000055e368e8b629 n/a (chrome + 0x4945629)#012#25 0x000055e368e39dc8 n/a (chrome + 0x48f3dc8)#012#26 0x000055e368e8c1fc n/a (chrome + 0x49461fc)#012#27 0x000055e368e60861 n/a (chrome + 0x491a861)#012#28 0x000055e36de38b19 n/a (chrome + 0x98f2b19)#012#29 0x000055e368dcda88 n/a (chrome + 0x4887a88)#012#30 0x000055e368dcbdaa n/a (chrome + 0x4885daa)#012#31 0x000055e3665aa4c4 ChromeMain (chrome + 0x20644c4)#012#32 0x00007f730528ecb2 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6 + 0x28cb2)#012#33 0x000055e36626c46a _start (chrome + 0x1d2646a)#012#012Stack trace of thread 5:#012#0  0x00007f7306a6fc06 futex_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0xfc06)#012#1  0x000055e368ec834d n/a (chrome + 0x498234d)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8cc6 n/a (chrome + 0x4982cc6)#012#3  0x000055e368ec893e n/a (chrome + 0x498293e)#012#4  0x000055e368e39e37 n/a (chrome + 0x48f3e37)#012#5  0x000055e368e8c1fc n/a (chrome + 0x49461fc)#012#6  0x000055e368e60861 n/a (chrome + 0x491a861)#012#7  0x000055e368ea5669 n/a (chrome + 0x495f669)#012#8  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#9  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#10 0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 2:#012#0  0x00007f730537f56e epoll_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x11956e)#012#1  0x000055e368ff7b0b n/a (chrome + 0x4ab1b0b)#012#2  0x000055e368ff54eb n/a (chrome + 0x4aaf4eb)#012#3  0x000055e368ed92f3 n/a (chrome + 0x49932f3)#012#4  0x000055e368e8c1fc n/a (chrome + 0x49461fc)#012#5  0x000055e368e60861 n/a (chrome + 0x491a861)#012#6  0x000055e368e9e56d n/a (chrome + 0x495856d)#012#7  0x000055e368ea5669 n/a (chrome + 0x495f669)#012#8  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#9  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#10 0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 3:#012#0  0x00007f7306a7007f futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0x1007f)#012#1  0x000055e368ec84e8 n/a (chrome + 0x49824e8)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8b73 n/a (chrome + 0x4982b73)#012#3  0x000055e368e9f66e n/a (chrome + 0x495966e)#012#4  0x000055e368e9f26d n/a (chrome + 0x495926d)#012#5  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#6  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#7  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 4:#012#0  0x00007f730537f56e epoll_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x11956e)#012#1  0x000055e368ff7b0b n/a (chrome + 0x4ab1b0b)#012#2  0x000055e368ff54eb n/a (chrome + 0x4aaf4eb)#012#3  0x000055e368ed92f3 n/a (chrome + 0x49932f3)#012#4  0x000055e368e8c1fc n/a (chrome + 0x49461fc)#012#5  0x000055e368e60861 n/a (chrome + 0x491a861)#012#6  0x000055e368ea5669 n/a (chrome + 0x495f669)#012#7  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#8  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#9  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 12:#012#0  0x00007f7306a7007f futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0x1007f)#012#1  0x000055e368ec84e8 n/a (chrome + 0x49824e8)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8b73 n/a (chrome + 0x4982b73)#012#3  0x000055e368e9f66e n/a (chrome + 0x495966e)#012#4  0x000055e368e9f26d n/a (chrome + 0x495926d)#012#5  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#6  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#7  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 10:#012#0  0x00007f7306a6fc06 futex_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0xfc06)#012#1  0x000055e368ec834d n/a (chrome + 0x498234d)#012#2  0x000055e36de2a39d n/a (chrome + 0x98e439d)#012#3  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#4  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#5  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 9:#012#0  0x00007f7306a6fc06 futex_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0xfc06)#012#1  0x000055e368ec834d n/a (chrome + 0x498234d)#012#2  0x000055e36de2a39d n/a (chrome + 0x98e439d)#012#3  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#4  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#5  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 7:#012#0  0x00007f7306a7007f futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0x1007f)#012#1  0x000055e368ec84e8 n/a (chrome + 0x49824e8)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8b73 n/a (chrome + 0x4982b73)#012#3  0x000055e368e39e0f n/a (chrome + 0x48f3e0f)#012#4  0x000055e368e8c1fc n/a (chrome + 0x49461fc)#012#5  0x000055e368e60861 n/a (chrome + 0x491a861)#012#6  0x000055e368a063b4 n/a (chrome + 0x44c03b4)#012#7  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#8  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#9  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 14:#012#0  0x00007f7306a7007f futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0x1007f)#012#1  0x000055e368ec84e8 n/a (chrome + 0x49824e8)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8b73 n/a (chrome + 0x4982b73)#012#3  0x000055e368e9f66e n/a (chrome + 0x495966e)#012#4  0x000055e368e9f26d n/a (chrome + 0x495926d)#012#5  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#6  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#7  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 6:#012#0  0x00007f7306a7007f futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0x1007f)#012#1  0x000055e368ec84e8 n/a (chrome + 0x49824e8)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8b73 n/a (chrome + 0x4982b73)#012#3  0x000055e368e9f66e n/a (chrome + 0x495966e)#012#4  0x000055e368e9f26d n/a (chrome + 0x495926d)#012#5  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#6  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#7  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 8:#012#0  0x00007f7306a6fc06 futex_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0xfc06)#012#1  0x000055e368ec834d n/a (chrome + 0x498234d)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8cc6 n/a (chrome + 0x4982cc6)#012#3  0x000055e368ec893e n/a (chrome + 0x498293e)#012#4  0x000055e368e9f690 n/a (chrome + 0x4959690)#012#5  0x000055e368e9f29d n/a (chrome + 0x495929d)#012#6  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a (chrome + 0x49864e4)#012#7  0x00007f7306a69590 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9590)#012#8  0x00007f730537f223 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0x119223)#012#012Stack trace of thread 13:#012#0  0x00007f7306a6fc06 futex_wait_cancelable (libpthread.so.0 + 0xfc06)#012#1  0x000055e368ec834d n/a (chrome + 0x498234d)#012#2  0x000055e368ec8cc6 n/a (chrome + 0x4982cc6)#012#3  0x000055e368ec893e n/a (chrome + 0x498293e)#012#4  0x000055e368e39e37 n/a (chrome + 0x48f3e37)#012#5  0x000055e368e8c1fc n/a (chrome + 0x49461fc)#012#6  0x000055e368e60861 n/a (chrome + 0x491a861)#012#7  0x000055e368ea5669 n/a (chrome + 0x495f669)#012#8  0x000055e368ecc4e4 n/a 
Mar  2 07:33:38 victor systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@3-4003-0.service: Succeeded.
```

```
Mar  3 08:33:29 victor gnome-shell[17417]: Hit MOZ_CRASH([unhandlable oom] ExecutableAllocator::reprotectPool) at /build/firefox-1cAqEX/firefox-86.0+build3/js/src/vm/JSContext.cpp:1185
Mar  3 08:33:29 victor kernel: [ 3377.738711] DOM Worker[21161]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fbf63159aa9 sp 00007fbf399560e0 error 6 in libxul.so[7fbf5f73f000+5148000]
Mar  3 08:33:29 victor kernel: [ 3377.738719] Code: 00 48 8d 35 99 14 bb 02 49 89 e6 4c 89 f7 48 89 da 31 c0 e8 e9 61 6f fc 4c 89 f7 e8 1a 00 00 00 48 8b 05 42 29 fb 03 4c 89 30 <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 a3 04 00 00 e8 4f eb 5e fc 53 48 89 fa 48 8b
```

```
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[13040]: [unhandlable oom] Failed to mmap, likely no more mappings available /build/firefox-1cAqEX/firefox-86.0+build3/memory/build/mozjemalloc.cpp : 1306
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: message repeated 5 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: g_atomic_ref_count_dec: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (arc) > 0' failed
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: message repeated 3 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: free(): invalid pointer
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 6
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: == Stack trace for context 0x560fa7763240 ==
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor gnome-shell[5778]: g_atomic_ref_count_dec: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (arc) > 0' failed
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor systemd[2496]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor systemd[2496]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor systemd[2496]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor systemd[2496]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Mar  3 08:10:41 victor systemd[2496]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

```
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: message repeated 9 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: JS ERROR: out of memory
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: message repeated 65 times: [ JS ERROR: out of memory]
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: message repeated 2 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: JS ERROR: out of memory
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: message repeated 66 times: [ JS ERROR: out of memory]
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: message repeated 2 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: JS ERROR: out of memory
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: message repeated 51 times: [ JS ERROR: out of memory]
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockBox is on because it needs an allocation.
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: Can't update stage views actor Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_dash_DashToDock_MyDash is on because it needs an allocation.
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: Can't update stage views actor dash is on because it needs an allocation.
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: Can't update stage views actor dashtodockDashScrollview is on because it needs an allocation.
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: Can't update stage views actor StBoxLayout is on because it needs an allocation.
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: Can't update stage views actor Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_dash_DashToDock_MyDashItemContainer is on because it needs an allocation.
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 11
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ab2d744220 ==
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: #0   55ab32a9bfe0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1625 (3c33905d1100 @ 221)
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: #1   55ab32a9bf48 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1590 (3c33905d11f0 @ 22)
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: #2   55ab32a9beb8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:82 (3b66bd84bf0 @ 39)
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor gnome-shell[88500]: #3   55ab32a9be28 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:167 (3b66bd848d0 @ 14)
Mar  2 10:47:32 victor systemd[1]: Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
Mar  2 10:47:39 victor systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Mar  2 10:47:41 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Mar  2 10:47:41 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Mar  2 10:47:41 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Mar  2 10:47:41 victor systemd[2524]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Mar  2 10:47:41 victor systemd[2524]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

```
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: Failed to allocate texture: Out of memory
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: Failed to allocate texture: Out of memory
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: Failed to allocate texture: Out of memory
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: Failed to allocate texture: Out of memory
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: message repeated 5 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: free(): invalid pointer
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 6
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: g_atomic_ref_count_dec: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (arc) > 0' failed
Mar  2 14:37:16 victor gnome-shell[117354]: == Stack trace for context 0x55a5e5dcc2a0 ==
Mar  2 14:37:27 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Mar  2 14:37:27 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Mar  2 14:37:27 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Mar  2 14:37:27 victor systemd[2524]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Mar  2 14:37:27 victor systemd[2524]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

```
Mar  2 15:09:45 victor dbus-daemon[2535]: [session uid=1000 pid=2535] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.577' (uid=1000 pid=133914 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Mar  2 15:09:45 victor dbus-daemon[2535]: [session uid=1000 pid=2535] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.577' (uid=1000 pid=133914 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Mar  2 15:09:45 victor dbus-daemon[2535]: [session uid=1000 pid=2535] Activating service name='org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService' requested by ':1.577' (uid=1000 pid=133914 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Mar  2 15:09:45 victor dbus-daemon[2535]: [session uid=1000 pid=2535] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
Mar  2 15:09:45 victor dbus-daemon[2535]: [session uid=1000 pid=2535] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService'
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor dbus-daemon[2535]: [session uid=1000 pid=2535] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider'
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: JS ERROR: out of memory
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: message repeated 8 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: g_atomic_ref_count_dec: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (arc) > 0' failed
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: message repeated 3 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: free(): invalid pointer
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 6
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: g_atomic_ref_count_dec: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (arc) > 0' failed
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor gnome-shell[133914]: == Stack trace for context 0x55d76c85e270 ==
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Mar  2 15:09:46 victor systemd[2524]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Mar  2 15:09:47 victor systemd[2524]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Mar  2 15:09:47 victor systemd[2524]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

Related Firefox crash reports: [1](https://crash-stats.mozilla.org/report/index/2e4f34cf-f569-4ab9-a776-ae7810210303), [2](https://crash-stats.mozilla.org/report/index/50e50626-48dd-48e7-94e0-3015a0210303), [3](https://crash-stats.mozilla.org/report/index/b8d7431a-83d3-45ab-b8d1-387610210303).

**Edit:** more crashes with different info. The Chromium crash references an Intel graphics driver. The first `gnome-shell` crash happened when clicking the clock to open the notification/calendar popup, as is referenced in the stack trace. The second has a different signal than the others (11 instead of 6).

```
Mar  3 15:11:51 victor kernel: [20762.954881] chrome[9987]: segfault at 20 ip 00007efc55a4ade4 sp 00007ffdcd89fc70 error 6 in i965_dri.so[7efc553fd000+b8d000]
Mar  3 15:11:51 victor kernel: [20762.954890] Code: 84 00 00 00 00 00 84 c9 74 7c f3 0f 10 0a f3 0f 10 42 04 0f 2e c8 0f 86 da 00 00 00 66 0f 7e c9 31 f6 0f 1f 40 00 48 83 c2 18 <89> 30 89 48 
04 48 83 c0 08 48 39 d7 74 6e 80 bb b3 97 00 00 00 0f
```

```
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: message repeated 2 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: JS ERROR: Error: Must pass an exception and optionally a message to logError()#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/_signals.js:142:25#012close@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:954:14#012toggle@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:803:18#012vfunc_event@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/panelMenu.js:137:23
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: JS ERROR: out of memory
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: JS ERROR: out of memory
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: **
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: Clutter:ERROR:../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:1372:clutter_actor_set_mapped: assertion failed: (CLUTTER_ACTOR_IS_MAPPED (self))
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: Bail out! Clutter:ERROR:../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:1372:clutter_actor_set_mapped: assertion failed: (CLUTTER_ACTOR_IS_MAPPED (self))
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 6
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: == Stack trace for context 0x5589d4a8b270 ==
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: #0   5589d75ed058 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/calendar.js:881 (328308a437e0 @ 45)
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: #1   5589d75ecfa8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/boxpointer.js:82 (3c1efecef970 @ 192)
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: #2   5589d75ecee8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:933 (3c1efecf9ba0 @ 207)
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: #3   7fff6dd2cf70 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:805 (3c1efecf9e20 @ 91)
Mar  3 15:15:48 victor gnome-shell[19012]: #4   7fff6dd2d020 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/panelMenu.js:137 (328308a79ce0 @ 126)
Mar  3 15:15:59 victor systemd[2496]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Mar  3 15:15:59 victor systemd[2496]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Mar  3 15:15:59 victor systemd[2496]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Mar  3 15:15:59 victor systemd[2496]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Mar  3 15:15:59 victor systemd[2496]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

```
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: JS ERROR: out of memory
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: message repeated 15 times: [ JS ERROR: out of memory]
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: message repeated 3 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: shmat failed
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: shmget failed
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: XXX: resource creation failed
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: message repeated 7 times: [ XXX: resource creation failed]
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 11
Mar  4 11:03:33 victor gnome-shell[3265]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e544c5f230 ==
Mar  4 11:03:34 victor systemd[2745]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Mar  4 11:03:34 victor slack.desktop[10765]: [03/04/21, 11:03:34:256] info: [FOCUS-EVENT] Client window focused
Mar  4 11:03:34 victor systemd[2745]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Mar  4 11:03:34 victor systemd[2745]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Mar  4 11:03:34 victor systemd[2745]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
Mar  4 11:03:34 victor systemd[2745]: Starting GNOME Shell on X11...
```

The curious thing is that even though these logs mention frequent 'out of memory' issues, nothing suggests that the system is actually running out of memory:
monitoring free memory shows that there is enough available, swap is not touched, no processes are killed by `oomkiller`, and the system doesn't become sluggish in any way (just a clean crash).

What I've already done/tried:

- A full run of memtest86 doesn't throw up any errors.
- File system checks and SMART checks look fine.
- The crashes remain when using other window managers (Wayland, xfce).

I'm a bit stumped by these errors, as memory seems to be the culprit but it's not clear why. I'd appreciate any help. Always happy to add more logs or try things out.

For completeness, a `grep` on `memory` in the startup logs:

```
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.011159] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.012174] Early memory node ranges
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036556] Reserving Intel graphics memory at [mem 0x7d800000-0x7f7fffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036921] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036923] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00058000-0x00058fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036925] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036927] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x67b0d000-0x67b0dfff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036929] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x67b1d000-0x67b1dfff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036930] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x67b1e000-0x67b1efff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036931] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x67b3b000-0x67b3bfff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036933] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x69e9a000-0x69e9afff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036934] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x69e9b000-0x69e9bfff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036936] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x765c3000-0x76648fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036938] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x7a157000-0x7a4e1fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036939] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x7a4e2000-0x7a523fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036939] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x7a524000-0x7ae59fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036940] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x7ae5a000-0x7b5fefff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036942] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x7b600000-0x7f7fffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036943] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x7f800000-0xefffffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036944] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036945] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfdffffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036945] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe000000-0xfe010fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036946] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe011000-0xfebfffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036947] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036948] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec01000-0xfedfffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036949] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036949] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xfeffffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.036950] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.126064] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.595529] Freeing initrd memory: 55380K
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.615362] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.927939] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2040K
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.929149] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2644K
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.931423] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2044K
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    0.932485] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1440K
Mar  3 07:37:19 victor kernel: [    1.287118] i2c i2c-0: 2/2 memory slots populated (from DMI)
```

System info:

```
Ubuntu version: 20.10
Kernel: 5.8.0-44-generic x86_64
Gnome version: 3.38.3
gnome-shell version: 3.38.2-1ubuntu1~20.10.1
CPU: Dual Core Intel Core i7-7600U (-MT MCP-) 2.8 GHz 
RAM: 16 GB (shown as 15.5 GiB in Ubuntu settings)
Swap space: 2 GB
Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Graphics driver: i915
Window system: X11
```

Comment: Based on messages like `message repeated 51 times: [ JS ERROR: out of memory]`, I would concur that there are memory constraints on the machine. What else is running on the computer? Have you used a tool like `htop` or `glances` to see where all the memory is going? 2GB for swap may be insufficient if you enjoy having several dozen browser tabs open, as there would be nowhere to deposit idle cache ...

Comment: The reproducible issue with the NYTimes page happens even right after boot, without anything else running. With `watch -n 0.1 free -h`, I don't see any moment when memory is low (3.4 GiB used, 4.8 GiB free, 1.6 GiB shared, 7.3 GiB buff/cache, 10 GiB available). Swap is not used at all (0 B). The system doesn't get slow at all. The top memory consuming process is Chromium itself; there doesn't seem to be any apparent memory leak of `gnome-shell` (as I've read in other issues).

Comment: I don't really understand 'nowhere to deposit idle cache', would you care to explain? :)

Comment: "Idle cache" would be "things in memory that aren't being used right this second". When the system starts to run out of memory, it will move "idle cache" from RAM to the swap file based on various configurations. In the event the RAM is full and the swap is full, then there's "nowhere to deposit" that cache. If the swap is not used and RAM is still available, then the issue is likely somewhere else. Chrome has a hard limit of 4GB of memory consumption per tab before it kills the process unless you've "tweaked" it ...

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tweaked Chrome limits, but watching the Chromium task manager, I don't see memory consumption for the tab get anywhere near 4GB (more like 200MB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, it turned out that the maximum number of memory mappings (`vm.max_map_count`) was set too low (3096).

I permanently increased it to 262144 by adding `vm.max_map_count=262144` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (helped by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295424/mmap-fails-with-enomem) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889241/how-to-increase-vm-max-map-count) StackOverflow question), which seems to solve the issues (at least the browser don't reliably crash anymore on memory-intensive pages).